# python pandas Slicing datetime dates by number of rows

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Lets say I have a time series

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

dates = pd.date_range('12/31/2014', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Given a date such as  `d ='1/5/2015'` how would I select the rows two days after d (days = 1/6/2015, 1/7/2015) and two days before d (days = 1/4/2015, 1/3/2015)? Is there a way to do this to ignore missing data from either weekends or holidays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

d = pd.Timestamp('1/5/2015')
two_bdays_before = d - BDay(2)   # business days
two_bdays_later = d + BDay(2)
```

Then to access all days between `two_bdays_before` and `two_bdays_later`:

```
>>> df[two_bdays_before:two_bdays_later]]
                   A         B         C         D
2015-01-01  0.741045 -0.051576  0.228247 -0.429165
2015-01-02 -0.312247 -0.391012 -0.256515 -0.849694
2015-01-03 -0.581522 -1.472528  0.431249  0.673033
2015-01-04 -1.408855  0.564948  1.019376  2.986657
2015-01-05 -0.566606 -0.316533  1.201412 -1.390179
2015-01-06 -0.052672  0.293277 -0.566395 -1.591686
2015-01-07 -1.669806  1.699540  0.082697 -1.229178
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.index.get_loc(d)` returns an integer index corresponding to the date represented by the date string `d`.

You can then use that integer index to select 2 rows before or after `d` in `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('12/31/2014', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
d = '1/5/2015'

idx = df.index.get_loc(d)
print(df.iloc[idx+1:idx+3])
#                    A         B         C         D
# 2015-01-06  1.211569  1.766432  0.153963  1.101142
# 2015-01-07  0.018377  0.112825  0.347711 -1.400145

print(df.iloc[idx-2:idx])
#                    A         B         C         D
# 2015-01-03 -0.507956 -1.389623 -0.092228 -0.104655
# 2015-01-04  0.206824  1.226987  0.253424 -0.529778
```

Comment: If there is missing data will this ignore it? or will it throw a error?

Comment: What do you mean by missing data? Dates for which there is no row, or do you mean values of `d` which are missing in `df.index`?

Comment: By missing dates I mean you have an array [1/1/2000, 1/3/2000, 1/4/2000]. you are missing 1/2/2000. Would the code skip from 1/1/2000 to 1/3/2000?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes, the method above would skip missing values like `1/2/2000` since  `idx+1:idx+3` is referencing rows by ordinal not by value.

Comment: However, if `d` is not in `df.index`, then the `get_loc`  method would raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: And I guess I should expect `idx+ some number out of df` would also raise an error too since you would not get values in the index.

Comment: Actually, you would simply get an empty DataFrame if `idx+1:idx+3` is too large or too small. Try `df.iloc[101:103]` for example.